# What is "Theme Counter" in r shiny reactive log graphics generated by {reactlog}?

Tags: r, shiny

The `reactlog::reactlog_enable()` function generates an input node called "Theme Counter".  Does anybody know what that is representing and where it is documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `reactiveVal` defined [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/fd7518018cbb2ec0b89960c922e34576d5dbc1e7/R/shiny.R#L755) which is used to [create a reactive dependency](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/fd7518018cbb2ec0b89960c922e34576d5dbc1e7/R/shiny.R#L1371) when `setCurrentTheme` is called for the according shiny session.

[setCurrentTheme](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/fd7518018cbb2ec0b89960c922e34576d5dbc1e7/R/shiny.R#L1345) is described as follows:

> ```
>   # This function does three things: (1) sets theme as the current
>   # bootstrapTheme, (2) re-executes any registered theme dependencies, and
>   # (3) sends the resulting dependencies to the client.
> ```